# Linux Mint - System notifications disappear without doing anything

Tags: linux, cinnamon, desktop, notifications

I'd like to have my system notifications remain active until I manually mark them as read. Unfortunately they disappear without doing anything. What do I need to change?

These are my preferences:

[image]

[image]